# How can I animate a text change in swift or objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, animation, catransition

I tried a test-project. It worked but the method I used, put programmatically created labels over old existing labels. When the length of a string array is lower than the old one, it shows unnecessary old labels due to addSubview method.
How can I handle this problem?

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func pushTransition(duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation:CATransition = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
            kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        animation.type = kCATransitionPush
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
        animation.duration = duration
        self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: kCATransitionPush)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var current:Float = 125.24
    var discount:Float = 1.212342748

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func doAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let currentstr = String(format: "₺%.2f", self.current)
    let length = currentstr.characters.count
    var strarray = Array(currentstr.characters)
    strarray[length-3] = ","
    print(strarray)
    self.current = self.current-self.discount
    let newcurrent = String(format: "₺%.2f", self.current)
    let newcurrentlength = newcurrent.characters.count
    var newcurrentarray = Array(newcurrent.characters)
    newcurrentarray[newcurrentlength-3] = ","
    print(newcurrentarray)
    var labels = [UILabel]()
    print(labels)
    if (length == newcurrentlength) {
        for i in 1 ..< length+1 {
            labels.append(UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((15*CGFloat(i)), 100, 20, 20)))
            if (strarray[i-1] == newcurrentarray[i-1]){
                print("SAME")
                labels[i-1].text = String(newcurrentarray[i-1])
                labels[i-1].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                labels[i-1].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                self.view.addSubview(labels[i-1])

            } else {
                print("CHANGED")
                labels[i-1].pushTransition(0.4)
                labels[i-1].text = String(newcurrentarray[i-1])
                labels[i-1].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                labels[i-1].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                self.view.addSubview(labels[i-1])
            }
        }
    } else {
        for i in 1..<newcurrentlength+1 {
            labels.append(UILabel(frame: CGRectMake((15*CGFloat(i)), 100, 20, 20)))
            if (strarray[i-1] == newcurrentarray[i-1]){
                print("SAME")
                labels[i-1].text = String(newcurrentarray[i-1])
                labels[i-1].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                labels[i-1].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                self.view.addSubview(labels[i-1])
            } else {
                print("CHANGED")
                labels[i-1].pushTransition(0.4)
                labels[i-1].text = String(newcurrentarray[i-1])
                labels[i-1].textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                labels[i-1].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                self.view.addSubview(labels[i-1])
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

I put label array out of action section and it's fixed.

```
        var labels = [UILabel]()
```

However, the transition between 100,00 and 99,99 there is a problem with the last child of label array. It still shows last digit like 99,990

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you adding new labels? Why not reuse the same one and just change the text?

Comment: you mean labels.append() ?

Comment: No, addSubview. You should not be adding many many views

Comment: so how can I handle it? Could you please give me an example over my project?